# Authorization supported in Devise for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authorization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've implemented Devise for a Rails 3.2.8 app.  Very easy, seems to work fine.  But the documentation suggests creating a whole separate table with email/passwords for an admin role.  I need admins in our system to also be treated like users, they just have extra permissions.  Does Devise help in this or are there good extensions for authorization?  Or am I expected to create an additional Role model or field in the User model to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requirements are simple, you may just add a boolean column in your users table called "is_admin" and check against it everytime you need extra permissions.

For a systematic solution, check out [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) by ryanb(Railscasts author)